# How to use borrowObject of GenericObjectPool class such that threads don't get stuck?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons, apache-commons-pool

I am using the apache commons pool2 version 2.8.1. While borrowing object from pool, threads are getting stuck.
I initialised the pool size as 1. And had 3 threads created.
First thread enters borrowObject method, since there are no idle objects to poll from, it will create one object and move forward.

```
p = (PooledObject)this.idleObjects.pollFirst();
if (p == null) {
  p = this.create();
  if (p != null) {
     create = true;
  }
}
```

The other two threads will also follow same path and check for idle objects(there are none), will try to create one object but the pool size is set to 1. Thus, the two threads will move forward and enter **idleObjects.takeFirst()** function.
Value of blockWhenExhausted is true and borrowMaxWaitMillis is -1 as we don't want timeout.

```
if (blockWhenExhausted) {
   if (p == null) {
      if (borrowMaxWaitMillis < 0L) {
           p = (PooledObject)this.idleObjects.takeFirst();
      } else {
           p = (PooledObject)this.idleObjects.pollFirst(borrowMaxWaitMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      }
   }

   if (p == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Timeout waiting for idle object");
   }
}
```

Now, the main thread does **this.factory.activateObject(p);** and object gets activated. Now, when the validation is checked **validate = this.factory.validateObject(p);** it comes out to be false as provider might have been disconnected.

So, the object is destroyed by calling **this.destroy(p);**

```
private void destroy(PooledObject<T> toDestroy) throws Exception {
     toDestroy.invalidate();
     this.idleObjects.remove(toDestroy);
     this.allObjects.remove(new BaseGenericObjectPool.IdentityWrapper(toDestroy.getObject()));

     try {
        this.factory.destroyObject(toDestroy);
     } finally {
        this.destroyedCount.incrementAndGet();
        this.createCount.decrementAndGet();
     }
}
```

The object which was created is now destroyed and removed from idleObject and allObjects list. Now, the other two threads are still waiting to take object from idle objects list but there are no object present. Hence, the two threads are in wait state for infinite period and the application waits forever until we kill the process.

```
public E takeFirst() throws InterruptedException {
   this.lock.lock();

   Object var2;
   try {
      Object x;
      while((x = this.unlinkFirst()) == null) {
         this.notEmpty.await();
      }

      var2 = x;
    } finally {
      this.lock.unlock();
    }
    return var2;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the other code involved? You mentioned: _the main thread does this.factory.activateObject(p); and object gets activated. Now, when the validation is checked validate = this.factory.validateObject(p);_; also this: _the object is destroyed by calling this.destroy(p);_. It sounds like the issue is that "destroy()" is being called, that doesn't sound right. Instead, you want something like `returnObject(p)` to make it available again.